# How do I complete "This Ain't My First Rodeo" Badass Challenge?

Tags: borderlands-2

The challenge states:

> Explore your way to the top of the Happy Pig Motel sign

I've tried various forms of parkour off the nearby tower and rooftops and can't make it up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A friend pointed out that there are nearby geysers that shoot you way up in the air.  By properly timing a run into the closest geyser (or simply standing in the right place), it is possible to land on top of the big pig, which will net you challenge success.

This YouTube video pretty much sums it up:

Answer (score 2):

The closest geyser just needs to be stood on at the correct spot. It will launch you high enough that you will have ample time to adjust your decent onto the pig. You don't have to run at the geyser.

It took me 10-15 minutes to find the sweet spot on the geyser but after that it could be done with ~90% accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the geyser in front of the motel to get to the top of the pig sign. you have to stand on the edge(nearest to pig sign) of the geyser. Standing on center wont help you.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done with Krieg. His mass is increased so he doesn't get knocked around much, especially while using his action skill, and it keeps the geyser from lifting him enough. As of yet, I don't think Krieg can complete this challenge.